# Design customer table in a relationship with tables Contact and Legal Entity

Tags: database-design

I have two tables with the following attributes (fields):

### Contact

- IDContact
- Lastname
- Firstname
- Fathername
- IDGender
- Salutation
- DateOfBirth
- ...

### LegalEnity

- IDLegalEntity
- Name
- LegalName
- IDLegalForm
- ...

In my database I would like to store information about **Customers**.

### Customer

- IDCustomer
- TaxIDNumber
- IDTaxAuthority
- ...

Customers can be either a physical person (**Contact**) or a company (**Legal Entity**).
How should table **Customer** be related with table **Contact** and table **Legal Entity** in order to use a unique CustomerID (primary key) in other tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually done by implementing a super-type table.  You make `LegalEntity` and `Contact` sub-types by placing a foreign key in each of the sub-type tables pointing to the super-type.  You might call it something like `PotentialCustomer`.

Then you add a foreign key from the `Customer` table to the appropriate super-type record (in PotentialCustomer).  This lets you link customer records to only one table, avoiding multiple nullable foreign keys.

It also lets you have a single instance of a super-type which happens to be more than one sub-type at the same time.  This may not apply in your case, but it is often the case in situations where you have legal entities that play specific roles with respect to your business.  For example, many times your vendors can also be your customers.

Comment: This is correct.  In addition, I would direct Thanasis to the info tab under [Tag:class-table-inheritance]

Answer (score 0):

I would change things around quite a bit.  First, get rid of the goofy ID naming scheme you have there.  Starting everything with ID just looks weird.  Typically you would end it with ID, and most ORM's are going to look for conventions that end with ID.

Second, I wouldn't call your your physical person "Contact" unless they happen to be a Contact for a company.  Otherwise, call them Person.

Third, to use both depends on how you want to do it.  Do you want to treat all customers, people and legalentities alike?  If that's the case, you want a Customers table that has a UniqueID.  You use this same id as the primary key for your Person/Contact table and LegalEntity.  This creates a 1:1 mapping of customer to customer type, and they share a common ID system.

Answer (score 0):

Create a column CustomerType (Individual/Legal Entitiy) in Customer Table, create a foreign key CustomerId in LegalEntity and Contact (Child) Tables to refer column CustomerId in Customer (Parent)Table.